# No sound in asterisk 11.6

Tags: asterisk, telephony, avaya

I am using the asterisk 11.6 for IVR. Asterisk is getting calls from Avaya through E1 - CAS  pri line. One end of the PRI is connected in Avaya DS1 card and another end connected in IVR Telephony card ( Digium ). Avaya is transferring the calls to asterisk through the E1 - CAS PRI. Once the call is answered by the asterisk, there is no sound. But I am able to see the playing message in asterisk prompt using

```
asterisk -rvvvvvvvvvvvvv
```

But it is not happening for all the calls. It is happening only random calls. Please suggest what could be the reason?

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Reason can be settings of cisco or avaya.

Also can be not enought dsp on cisco.

For more info see cisco's "debug isdn pri"

Comment: Will be there any issue in asterisk? Because I am facing this issue in all the IVR.